# Отключение hover-эффектов через медиа-запросы CSS

Tags: html, css, html5

Как для мобильной версии сайта отключить hover-эффекты через медиа-запросы css?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Надеюсь, это вам поможет.

```
@media /*ваш запрос ширины экрана*/{

*:hover {
/*ваши параметры для отключения, к примеру
box-shadow: none;
*/
}
}
```